# How to use Repeater fields in Node JS Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, validation, error-handling

I am beginner to Node JS Express JS. I want to showing group of repeated fields and validated them and save in DB. I am using MongoDB. I am validating the form using middleware and it's working fine, errors are showing for non repeater fields. I can see errors for repeater fields, but not getting the correct way to display them. when I submit the form, page reloads and errors displays
for simple fields and only one block or repeater shows and other repeater blocks doesn't displays.

Also let me know is there any way to repeater fields errors in array like it's showing in posted data.
Please guide me so I can accomplish this task in correct way.
Thanks

Here is my code.

**Repeater block HTML**

```
<div data-repeater-list="tanent_info">
    <div data-repeater-item>
        <div class="card card-bordered card-stretch">
            <div class="card-inner-group">
                <div class="card-inner">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                            <label class="form-label" for="tanent_name">Tanent Name <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                            <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="tanent_name" name="tanent_info[tanent_name]" placeholder="Tanent Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                            <label class="form-label" for="tanent_phone">Phone <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                            <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="tanent_phone" name="tanent_info[tanent_phone]" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                            <label class="form-label" for="tanent_email">Email <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                            <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="tanent_email" name="tanent_info[tanent_email]" placeholder="Enter Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                            <label class="form-label" for="tanent_address">Address <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                            <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                    <textarea class="form-control no-resize" name="tanent_info[tanent_address]" id="tanent_address"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                            <label class="form-label" for="aadhar_front">Aadhar Card Front</label>
                            <div class="form-control-wrap">        
                                <div class="form-file">            
                                    <input type="file" name="tanent_info[aadhar_front]" class="form-file-input" id="customFile">
                                    <label class="form-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                                </div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                            <label class="form-label" for="aadhar_back">Aadhar Card Back</label>
                            <div class="form-control-wrap">        
                                <div class="form-file">            
                                    <input type="file" name="tanent_info[aadhar_back]" class="form-file-input" id="customFile">
                                    <label class="form-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>        
                                </div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                            <label class="form-label" for="pan_card">Pan Card</label>
                            <div class="form-control-wrap">        
                                <div class="form-file">            
                                    <input type="file" name="tanent_info[pan_card]" class="form-file-input" id="customFile">            
                                    <label class="form-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>        
                                </div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Remove Tenant" class="btn btn-danger"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Middleware code**

```
const express = require('express');
const { body } = require("express-validator");

const companyValidation = [
  body("company")
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("Please enter company name")
    .isString()
    .withMessage("company name should be string"),
  body("office_number")
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("Please select office number"),
  body("agreement_date")
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("Please select agreement date"),
  body("expiry_date")
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("Please select expiry date"),
  body("rent_amount")
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("Please enter rent amount")
    .isInt()
    .withMessage("Rent amount should be number only"),
  body("rent_start")
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("Please select rent start date"),
  body("status")
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("Please select tenant status"),
  body("security_paid")
    .optional()
    .if(body('security_paid').notEmpty())
    .isInt()
    .withMessage("Security Amount Paid should be number only"),
  body('tanent_info').optional(),
    body('tanent_info.*.tanent_name')
        .if(body('tanent_info').exists()) // check subfield only if 'company' exist
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage("Please enter tenant name"),
    body('tanent_info.*.tanent_name')
        .if(body('tanent_info').exists()) // check subfield only if 'company' exist
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage("Please enter tenant name"),
    body('tanent_info.*.tanent_name')
        .if(body('tanent_info').exists()) // check subfield only if 'company' exist
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage("Please enter tenant name"),
    body('tanent_info.*.tanent_name')
        .if(body('tanent_info').exists()) // check subfield only if 'company' exist
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage("Please enter tenant name"),
    body('tanent_info.*.tanent_name')
        .if(body('tanent_info').exists()) // check subfield only if 'company' exist
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage("Please enter tenant name"),    
];

module.exports = {
  companyValidation
}
```

**Posted data**

```
{
  company: 'test company',
  office_number: '',
  agreement_date: '',
  expiry_date: '',
  rent_amount: '',
  security_paid: '',
  status: '',
  rent_start: '',
  extention: '',
  agreement_number: '',
  agreement_document: '',
  notes: '',
  tanent_info: [
    {
      tanent_name: 'tenant1',
      tanent_phone: '',
      tanent_email: '',
      tanent_address: '',
      aadhar_front: '',
      aadhar_back: '',
      pan_card: ''
    },
    {
      tanent_name: '',
      tanent_phone: '',
      tanent_email: '',
      tanent_address: '',
      aadhar_front: '',
      aadhar_back: '',
      pan_card: ''
    },
    {
      tanent_name: 'tenant 2',
      tanent_phone: '',
      tanent_email: '',
      tanent_address: '',
      aadhar_front: '',
      aadhar_back: '',
      pan_card: ''
    }
  ],
  submit: ''
}
```

**Error receiving from middleware**

```
errors: [
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please select office number',
      path: 'office_number',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please select agreement date',
      path: 'agreement_date',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please select expiry date',
      path: 'expiry_date',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter rent amount',
      path: 'rent_amount',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Rent amount should be number only',
      path: 'rent_amount',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please select rent start date',
      path: 'rent_start',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please select tenant status',
      path: 'status',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter tenant name',
      path: 'tanent_info[1].tanent_name',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter tenant Phone number',
      path: 'tanent_info[0].tanent_phone',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter tenant Phone number',
      path: 'tanent_info[1].tanent_phone',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter tenant Phone number',
      path: 'tanent_info[2].tanent_phone',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter tenant email',
      path: 'tanent_info[0].tanent_email',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter tenant email',
      path: 'tanent_info[1].tanent_email',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter tenant email',
      path: 'tanent_info[2].tanent_email',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter tenant address',
      path: 'tanent_info[0].tanent_address',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter tenant address',
      path: 'tanent_info[1].tanent_address',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: '',
      msg: 'Please enter tenant address',
      path: 'tanent_info[2].tanent_address',
      location: 'body'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: still looking for suggestions. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: <% if(typeof formData!='undefined' && typeof formData.tanent_info != 'undefined') { %>
    <% for (let i = 0; i < formData.tanent_info.length; i++) { %>
        <% tanent_info = formData.tanent_info %>

<%  var key_name = 'tanent_info['+i+'].tanent_name'
                                            if(typeof errors!='undefined' &&  key_name in errors){  %>
                                               <p style="color: red;" class="error_msg"><%= errors[key_name].msg %></p>
                                        <%  }  %>

 <% } %>
<% } %>